# Solutions to the modular matrix equation $A^k=A^{-1}\,{\rm mod}\;p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}$This is a question about computing matrix inverses over finite prime fields $\,{\mathbb F}_p$

Given an $n\times n$ matrix of integers, one can calculate an inverse with rational elements, e.g.
$$A = \m{1&2&3\\5&7&11\\13&17&19}
\quad\implies\quad
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{24}\m{-54&13&1\\48&-20&4\\-6&9&-3}$$
The leading fraction $\left(\frac{1}{24}\right)$ can be replace with its modular inverse and multiplied with the matrix elements to produce an integer matrix modulo a prime, e.g.
for the above matrix
$$\eqalign{
A^{-1}
 &= \m{4&2&4\\2&0&1\\1&1&3}\,{\rm mod}\;5 \\\\
 &= \m{3&2&5\\2&5&6\\5&3&6}\,{\rm mod}\;7 \\\\
 &= \;etc \\
}$$
**NB:**   For $p=(2,3)\,$ the inverse doesn't exists
since $\,\det(A) = 24=0\,{\rm mod}\;p$

So I don't have any problem calculating the modular inverses, but I noticed that for some (sometimes very large) integer $k$ one obtains $\;A^k=A^{-1}\;{\rm mod}\;p$

Here's a table of minimal exponents for the matrix above
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|} \hline 
 p & k \\ \hline
5 & 9 \\ \hline
7 & 41 \\ \hline
11 & 1329 \\ \hline
13 & 2195 \\ \hline
17 & 4911 \\ \hline
19 & 3428 \\ \hline
23 & 32 \\ \hline
29 & 27 \\ \hline
31 & 29789 \\ \hline
37 & 1367 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Is there a formula for the minimum value of $k$ in terms of $p$ and some easily computed characteristics of the matrix (eigenvalues, singular values)?

Comment: Some quick thoughts. First of all, since we are given a priori that $A$ is invertible, $A^k = A^{-1}$ is equivalent to $A^{k+1} = I$. Second, if the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p(x)$, then $q(x) = x^{k+1} - 1$ satisfies $q(A) = 0$ if and only if $p(x)$ divides $q(x)$ as a polynomial over $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: A possibly useful result: an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ over $\Bbb F_p$ will always divide the polynomial $x^{p^d} - x$.

Comment: For your particular matrix, the characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^3 - 27x^2 - 77x - 24$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks. Perhaps an even better way to think of the problem is that matrices are periodic in modular arithmetic, i.e.  $A^{q+1}=A\;{\rm mod}\;p.\;$ Experimentally, the period seems to have a lower bound of $(p-1\le q)$ but no upper bound. It's reminiscent of the maximal periods of LFSRs in cryptography.

Comment: Well one consequence of what I've said, I believe, is that there is an upper bound of $q \leq p^n - 2$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix $A$. We could also get an upper bound (a weaker one) by using the pigeonhole principle

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm reading the comments from top to bottom so I hadn't seen that upper bound yet. Thanks again.  Even for my short table above I see that both the upper and lower bound are attained, i.e. for $\;p=(29,31)\;$

Comment: Another point of interest: $GL(n,\Bbb F_p)$ is a finite group, and as such [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) applies. In particular, the lowest $k$ for which $A^k = I$ must be a divisor of 
$$
|GL(n,\Bbb F_p)| = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(p^n - p^k).
$$
For $n = 3$, this gives us an upper bound of 
$$
q \leq 1 + |GL(n,\Bbb F_p)| = 1 + (p^3 - 1)(p^3 - p)(p^3  - p^2).
$$
I'm not sure how that compares to that other upper bound in general.

Comment: I didn't notice that the upper bound was attained for $p=31$, that's neat!

Comment: Sorry that should be $q \leq |GL(n,\Bbb F_p)|\color{red}{-1}$